# Instant Voice messaging app Android

Tags: android, instant-messaging

This is a fairly broad question. Im looking to create a voice messaging app for android as an after work project. Does anyone know of any specific apis that might help in this endeavor? Ive been looking at the google cloud messaging service but that seems more for update notifications. Ive also taken a look at the volley library but that doesnt support large data transfers. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be awesome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For short messages, I guess you'll be fine sending common http requests. I'd try with [ASIHttpRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), which features asynchronous get/post request, progress bar for large request, ...

Best of lucks.

**EDIT**

My bad, `ASIHttpRequest` is iOS exclusive. You can try [android-async-http](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http) instead.